# How can I increase size of array automatically as per user/programmer need at run time?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, vector, collections

I am writing code of Vector class of java and all other collection classes of Java but i am having problem that how it is possible to do that the size of array increase automatically at run time..
and program run properly without giving "Array out of bound Exception"
..
Well,This is my code

`/*  Developed By: Nitin_Khanna
    Date: 1/February/2018
    Github Username:beNitinhere
    Twitter Username:beNitinhere

*/
class Vector{

private static int[] A;
public static long  length;
//Default size of Vector is 10
      Vector(){

            length+=10;
             A= new int[10];
        }
//One-parameterized Costructor
       Vector(int n){
            length+=n;
             A= new int[n];
        }
//get
        public void get(){
            int []B=new int[5];
              for(int i=0;i<length();i++){
                 System.out.println(A[i]);
            }

        }
//lenght
        public static long length(){
            return length;
        }
//removeLastElement     
        public void removeLastElement(){
                length=length-1;
        }
//removeFirstElement        
        public void removeFirstElement(){
            for(int i=0;i<length();i++){
                A[i]=A[i+1];
            }
        }
//clear     
        public void clear(){
            length=0;
        }
//add       
        public void add(int num,int index){
            if(index>length()){
                set();
            }
            A[index]=num;
        }
//remove    
        public void remove(int index){
            for(int i=index;i<length();i++){
                A[i]=A[i+1];
            }
            length-=1;
        }
//firstElementIs        
        public int firstElementIs(){
            return A[0];
        }
//lastElementIs     
        public int lastElementIs(){
            return A[(int)length()-1];
        }
//elementAt     
        public int elementAt(int index){
            return A[index];

        }
        private void set(){
            length*=2;
            A=new int[(int)length];
        }
        public void size(){

        }
        // public boolean isEmpty(){

        // }
    public static void main(String args[]){
            Vector v1=new Vector(5);
                for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
                    v1.add(i,i);
                }
                v1.get();
                v1.removeLastElement();
                System.out.println("After calling removeLastElement function");
                v1.get();
                System.out.println("After calling remove function");
                v1.remove(2);
                v1.get();

        }
}`

Thanks in advance for help..

Comment: Once an array has its size declared, sin é. For those non-Irish speakers, that means: that’s it. It can’t be changed.

Comment: Take a look at how `ArrayList` is implemented.

Comment: `removeFirstElement()` has a bug. When `i` is equal to `length() - 1` the operation `A[i+1]` accesses the array out of bounds. Same for the rest of the `remove...` methods

Comment: i am writing code for Vector class not for array...Mr@notyou

Comment: @NitinKhanna You are using arrays to store your data, and it is true that you cannot resize an array.  You are able to create a new, larger array, and [copy the data into it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do so, but you can use [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or implement your own solution (Ziakad was right in the comment section when he stated this should be put into the Vector class. I was just giving a general description, but in the context of the question this is a good suggestion):

```
public static int[] raiseSize(int[] input, int newSize) {
    int[] output = new int[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) output[i] = input[i];
    return output;
}
```

Usage example:

```
int foo[] = new int[3];
foo[0] = 1; foo[1] = 2; foo[2] = 0;
foo = raiseSize(foo, 5);
```

Comment: With all respect, I think that `raiseSize` should be implemented in the `Vector` class. E.g. in the `add` method. When `Vector.size >= arr.length()` then call `raiseSize` with some incremental value...

Comment: You are doing the same as above solution.. It may be a possible solution  but with the increment in data amount program will slow

Comment: @zlakad you are right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Every program slows down when it operates on larger amount of data. This is how it's done in programming. You create a new array of a bigger size, then copy the elements. If you don't want to copy the range, consider using a list. EDIT: `ArrayList` and original java's `Vector` do this exact thing. They have internal representation as an array and when it becomes full, they create a new array, copy the elements and are ready to store more elements

Comment: @NitinKhanna yes, indeed, but the alternative is to use some kind of List, like ArrayList, as my answer suggested at its beginning.

Comment: up voted right now...

Comment: @LajosArpad `ArrayList` uses an array as internal representation and uses the mechanic of creating new array and copying the elements. `LinkedList` was what you meant, not `ArrayList`

Comment: Well my program works perfectly now.. thanks Mr@LajosArpad

Comment: @Fureeish you are right, I was not aware of that. Edited my answer.

Comment: @NitinKhanna you are welcome. You might consider accepting either this or Zlakad's answer, as both are correct. If an answer is accepted, it will help future visitors to instantly know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Read @notyou comment above. What you should do is MAKE another array with increased length, COPY all the elements (from old array) into this array and TELL to your code that the new array (NOW) is the data array.

Comment: Ya,this one may be possible solution but if data is in large ammount at that moment program will be slow..

Comment: You should carefully chose your initial size of underlying array, AND increment size (do not increment your array by 1 or 5)...

Comment: This is a correct answer I agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how an array is implemented: you specify the size of the array "in advance," and then the runtime sets aside enough consecutive memory locations to hold an array of a size you specify. The implication of this is that arrays can't be dynamically resized - you have *no idea* what's in the next consecutive memory location *after* the end of the array. Here's an illustration of an array of Boolean values of size 6:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| true  |  false | false | true | true | true (last item in the array) | ?? | ?? | ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0    |   1    |  2    |  3   |  4   | 5...
```

Side note: an interesting property of this is that you can figure out the memory address of any particular item with the following formula: `(initial memory location) + (array index * size of each memory location)`. For example, if the array starts at location 100 and every location is of size 2, the first item in the array is at location `100 + (2 * 0) = 100`. The item at index 3 is at location `100 + (2 * 3) = 106`. That's why you can access arbitrary locations in an array in constant time - you can do pointer arithmetic to find the location of an item at any arbitrary index.

**TL;DR** You can't dynamically resize arrays.

Comment: Ya,You are right but i am writing code for Vector class which is already have this feature in Java from jdk 1.1 .. So I just want to know which code works in the background of Vector class of Java

Comment: @NitinKhanna Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the Vector class doing something like what zlakad suggested in his answer?

Comment: Ya,May be it is possible that all the data of an array is copy into an another one in background but i am looking for an faster method... which i think is using Linked list instead of Array